# How to find the product in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I'm creating an eCommerce website to practice and during the process, I faced a problem.

I have a ProductDetails page where I should show me the exact product, however it's not working.

**App.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import ScrollToTop from "./hooks/ScrollToTop";

//components
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Shop from "./pages/Shop";
import ProductDetail from "./pages/ProductDetail";
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ScrollToTop>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/shop/:gender" exact component={Shop} />
          <Route path="/:productId" component={ProductDetail} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </ScrollToTop>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ProductDetails.jsx**
Here, I actually can get the id of a product but when I use array.find() it cannot find me that exact product.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hcoq.png). In this image, the first one represents the data. The second one, newProducts (array.find()). Third one is the id of product

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const ProductDetail = () => {
  const { productId } = useParams();

  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products);
  const newProduct = products.find((product) => product.id === productId);

  console.log(products);
  console.log(newProduct);
  console.log(productId);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <button></button>
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetail;
```

**Data**

```
const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Adidas Zapatillas Calcetin",
      image:
        "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0270/2098/4401/products/1_3aae263a-b58d-4318-a342-fe28ae51084e_900x.jpg?v=1595931237",
      price: "230.00",
      reminder: 5,
      gender: "men",
      categories: ["Boys", "Girls", "Slae", "Atlethik"],
      description:
        "Orange you glad to be standing fit and healthy on your feet? Whether skateboarding on the streets or rushing to make it to the front of a music gig, these orange",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Deluxe Brand Donna Super Star Scarpe",
      image:
        "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0270/2098/4401/products/15_05cf7145-5d0c-4adb-bec3-b07fb19a6397.jpg?v=1595931249",
      price: "20.00",
      reminder: 5,
      gender: "men",
      categories: ["Boys", "Girls", "Slae", "Atlethik"],
      description:
        "Orange you glad to be standing fit and healthy on your feet? Whether skateboarding on the streets or rushing to make it to the front of a music gig, these orange",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Premiata Hattori Sneakers",
      image:
        "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0270/2098/4401/products/10_f477c991-5323-4dfd-8a17-35312139f756.jpg?v=1595994440",
      price: "76.00",
      reminder: 5,
      gender: "women",
      categories: ["Boys", "Girls", "Slae", "Atlethik"],
      description:
        "Orange you glad to be standing fit and healthy on your feet? Whether skateboarding on the streets or rushing to make it to the front of a music gig, these orange",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "Urban Street Reverse Logo Sneakers",
      image:
        "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0270/2098/4401/products/12_4c3e324d-570e-4a7d-8e17-155bc782dcc4.jpg?v=1595994440",
      price: "30.00",
      reminder: 5,
      gender: "women",
      categories: ["Boys", "Girls", "Slae", "Atlethik"],
      description:
        "Orange you glad to be standing fit and healthy on your feet? Whether skateboarding on the streets or rushing to make it to the front of a music gig, these orange",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      title: "Urban Street Reverse Logo Sneakers",
      image:
        "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0270/2098/4401/products/15_05cf7145-5d0c-4adb-bec3-b07fb19a6397.jpg?v=1595931249",
      price: "30.00",
      reminder: 5,
      gender: "men",
      categories: ["Boys", "Girls", "Slae", "Atlethik"],
      description:
        "Orange you glad to be standing fit and healthy on your feet? Whether skateboarding on the streets or rushing to make it to the front of a music gig, these orange",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      title: "Urban Street Reverse Logo Sneakers",
      image:
        "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0270/2098/4401/products/1_3aae263a-b58d-4318-a342-fe28ae51084e_900x.jpg?v=1595931237",
      price: "30.00",
      reminder: 5,
      gender: "women",
      categories: ["Boys", "Girls", "Slae", "Atlethik"],
      description:
        "Orange you glad to be standing fit and healthy on your feet? Whether skateboarding on the streets or rushing to make it to the front of a music gig, these orange",
    },
  ],
});

export default productSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Could it be the '===' because the productId variable from the router could be a String and your id in the data is a number? Maybe try to cast one of the values or use '=='

Comment: Is it string vs int kind of thing? Add more console logs with `typeof` to see

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` or cast to integer the `productId`. Because `productId` is a string

Example

```
const newProduct = products.find((product) => product.id === parseInt(productId));
```